# When should you make an interface/contract, and when not?

Tags: php, oop, interface

As the title says: What are key points indicating you should use and interface. And what are key points indicating that you should **not** use an interface?

Comment: Explanation for why this is too broad? I'm asking for general key points, not starting a discussion about the use of interfaces.

Comment: As always - it depends. There is no general rule. Are the interfaces for DI/IOC, UnitTesting, or something else?

Comment: @Philipp It's for DI/IoC. I'm not asking for rules, just key points that would indicate you might want to consider using an interface instead of using an implementation directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interfaces are public "contracts" whenever you want to be able to swap the implementation or give someone the flexibility to use another implementation you should use interfaces.

Example:

You want to store something so you can load it later.
You could use something like

```
public function save(MySQL $db, array $data);
```

But this is not very flexible and it ties you code to a MySQL implementation.
If you want to be open for other implementations, because you are building an public library or framework or whatever, you should do something like this.

```
public function save(Persistance $storage, array $data)
{
    // dome some random stuff with you data
    ...
    $storage->save($data);
}
```

In this case `Persistence` is an interface and it could look something like this.

```
interface Persistance
{
    public function save(array $data);
}
```

And you local implementation could look like this.

```
class MySQL implements Persistance
{
    public function save(array $data)
    {
        $this->insert('my_table', $data);
    }
}
```

But somebody else could use your code with a complete different persistence layer, Redis or Postgres for example, just by implementing your interface and injecting their own `Persistence` implementation.

This is just a simple example, but Interfaces are mostly to understand as contracts between classes and leave the implementation open.

The opportunity to implement multiple interfaces is nice but has nothing to do with multiple inheritance. Interfaces only make sure a class has some clearly defined in- and outputs, but how things are done in the background is completely open.

If you really want get into 'multiple inheritance' you should have a look at Traits.

Interfaces are used in frameworks and the PHPFig is defining a lot of standard interfaces lately to make framework components more exchangeable.

For example the PSR-16 simple cache interface makes it possible to exchange the cache layer implementation between frameworks.

Or the PSR-7 Request Response interface enables frameworks to exchange standardized middleware implementations for login, CRF security or other stuff.

There is a PSR-11 Interface for dependency injection containers, if frameworks change their implementation from their own DI container to the interface we will be able to use those frameworks with different DI container implementations.

Comment: Seems pretty clear to me :) Does this mean that its pointless to write an interface when you're 99% sure that the implementation is not going to change?

Comment: "yes" or if you are the only one using it anyway ;)

Answer (score 0):

The entire point of interfaces is to give you the flexibility to have your class be forced to implement multiple interfaces, but still not allow multiple inheritance. The issues with inheriting from multiple classes are many and varied.

Interfaces are a compromise. Most of the problems with multiple inheritance don't apply to abstract base classes, so most modern languages these days disable multiple inheritance yet call abstract base classes interfaces and allows a class to "implement" as many of those as they want.

Comment: When you say "to have your class be forced to implement multiple interfaces" did you mean to say "be _allowed_ to implement multiple interfaces" - as in a replacement for multiple inheritance?

Comment: The sentence "most modern languages these days disable multiple inheritance yet call abstract base classes interfaces" is confusing me. Abstract base classes are an alternative way to allow multiple implementations, they don't need to have an interface as well; or are using meaning "interface" with a small `i` as opposed to "Interface" with a capital `I` to talk about the public methods of the abstract class?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean when you say "Most of the problems with multiple inheritance don't apply to abstract base classes"? An abstract base class is still a class and could suffer from multiple inheritance problems. Being abstract only means the class cannot be instantiated.